# Как в quasar vue повесить click на иконку компонента expansion?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar.js

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Во фреймворке quasar есть прекрасный компонент меню q-expansion-item
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так он выглядит.

У него есть режим expand-icon-toggle, который позволяет открывать меню только по клику на стрелочку.
Мне это и надо, но я не имею изначально список меню, а подгружаю его с back. Следовательно мне надо повесить обработчик на эту иконку.
Но т.к. она идет не слотом, я не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У компонента [`QExpansionItem`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/expansion-item#qexpansionitem-api) есть методы:

- `show` - показать (развернуть)
- `hide` - скрыть (свернуть)
- `toggle` - переключить на противоположное состояние

, и он эмитит события:

- `input`
- `show`
- `before-show`
- `hide`
- `before-hide`
- `after-show`
- `after-hide`

То есть, присутствуют все возможности и для программного открытия/закрытия, и для добавления обработчиков соответствующих событий.

Для доступа к экземплярам компонентов, обычно используются [рефы (референсы, ссылки)](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/component-template-refs.html) на них.
Добавив атрибут `ref="имяРефа"` одиночному элементу в шаблоне, доступ к нему можно получить через свойство экземпляра `$refs.имяРефа` (или `$refs['имяРефа']`, если имя не соответствует правилам именования свойств в JS). А добавив такой атрибут элементу в итерации `v-for`, доступ к рефу потребует указания еще и индекса: `$refs['имяРефа'][индекс]`.

Вызов метода компонента полученного по рефу, ничем не отличается от вызова метода js-объекта.
Добавление и удаление обработчиков событий - либо директивой `v-on` в шаблоне, либо по рефу через методы [`$on`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) и [`$off`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off).

---

Ниже простой пример, где раз в 2 секунды переключается (через `toggle`) элемент списка, выбранный по рефу случайным образом; и выполняется вывод в консоль из обработчика события `input` (на переключение курсором, обработчик конечно тоже реагирует).
<sub>Правда, увидеть эту забавность тут можно только открыв пример на всю страницу после его запуска, т.к. ифрейм слишком уж мелкий.</sub>

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data() { return {
    loading: false,
    icons: [],
    users: [],
  }},
  computed: {
    iconsCount() { return this.icons.length; },
  },
  methods: {
    printToggledItem(itmData, itmIdx, itmVal) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(`Элемент №${itmIdx + 1} (${itmData.name}) ${itmVal ? 'от' : 'за'}крыт`);
    },
    rndTo(to) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * to); },
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.loading = true;
    const usersUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
          iconsUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/material-design-icons/master/font/MaterialIconsOutlined-Regular.codepoints';
    this.users = await fetch(usersUrl).then(r => r.json());
    this.icons = (await fetch(iconsUrl).then(r => r.text()))
      .split(/\r?\n/).map(l => l.split(' ')[0]).filter(n => n.length);
    await (new Promise(yay => setTimeout(yay, 2e3)));
    this.loading = false;
    setInterval(() => {
      const itm = this.$refs['qexp-item'][this.rndTo(this.users.length)];
      itm.toggle();
    }, 2e3);
  },
});
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 350px">
    <q-card v-if="loading" flat bordered class="row items-center q-pa-lg">
      <q-circular-progress indeterminate size="50px" color="lime" class="col"></q-circular-progress>
      <div class="col">Загрузка...</div>
    </q-card>
    <q-list v-else bordered class="rounded-borders">
      <q-expansion-item v-for="(user, idx) in users" :key="user.id" ref="qexp-item"
        expand-separator expand-icon-toggle :icon="icons[rndTo(iconsCount)]"
        :label="user.name" :caption="user.email"
        @input="val => printToggledItem(user, idx, val)"
      >
        <q-card>
          <q-card-section>
            <div><b>From:</b> {{ user.address.city }}</div>
            <div><b>Phone:</b> {{ user.phone }}</div>
            <q-separator class="q-my-md"></q-separator>
            <div><b>Company:</b> {{ user.company.name }}</div>
            <div class="text-teal-9"><i>"{{ user.company.catchPhrase }}"<i></div>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </q-expansion-item>
  </div>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.20/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.20/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ